# Is there a way to change a superclass obj into a subclass obj?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an image class from a library and I'm trying to extend. The superclass methods return new superclass objects in several cases.  How can I use the subclass methods on the objects returned by the superclass methods? Is there a way to change a superclass object into a subclass object?

```
public class LibraryClass extends SomeBaseClass {
    LibraryClass someMethodThatChangesDataReturningNewObject() {
    }
}

public class MyClass extends LibraryClass {
    // methods that extends functionality

    // possible to override superclass method calling it and turning the LibraryClass 
    // obj into a MyClass obj and return that?
}

someRandomMethod() {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass;
    LibraryClass newObj = obj.someMethodThatChangesDataReturningNewObject();
    // possible to bind my subclass methods to newObj?
}
```

Comment: Valek - if you mean (LibraryClass)obj.  I guess I wasn't clear in my question.  If you mean (MyClass)newObj it's my understanding that won't work.  I was wondering if there was maybe a way to create a copy constructor that takes a superclass and returns a subclass.  Or some other means of making a wide class narrower.  Going from superclass to subclass.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  If you need to pass the newObj into a method that expects MyClass, then you should be able to do that as long as you observe Liskov Substitution Principle. What's your real problem?

Comment: Lie - You might be right I could be coming at this from the wrong angle.  I want to keep it generic because it's for a college course (no cheating) But I need to do something to the data of a picture (flip it horizontally) and wanted to create an inherited class with a method like flipHorizontal.  But I need to use other methods first from the base class before flipHorizontal to change other aspects of the picture.  They return the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
MyClass newObj = (MyClass) obj.someMethodThatChangesDataReturningNewObject();
```

You just need to make sure that your implementation of `MyClass.someMethodThatChangesDataReturningNewObject()` does in fact return an instance of `MyClass`.  If your implementation of that method just calls a parent implementation, then you'll be safer wrapping the cast in an if statement as follows:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
LibraryClass newLibraryClass = obj.someMethodThatChangesDataReturningNewObject();
if (newLibraryClass instanceof MyClass) {
    MyClass newObj = (MyClass) newLibraryClass;
    // MyClass specific processing here
}
```

In this case, if the object is not an instance of `MyClass`, you won't get a `ClassCastException`.  Just keep in mind that if its not an instance of `MyClass`, then that processing won't get executed.

The only other way to do it would be to create a constructor or other utility method that can create a new `MyClass` instance using the data from the `LibraryClass`.  That may or may not be possible, depending on whether the fields or getters/setters in `LibraryClass` are private, or protected/public.  Without knowing any of the details of `LibraryClass`, its hard to say.  But I would expect it to look similar to:

```
MyClass(LibraryClass libraryClass) {
    this.setField1(libraryClass.getField1());
    this.setField2(libraryClass.getField2());
    ...
}
```